# Kotlin map with function reference of a member function

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, reference

Given the following two classes:

```
class Parent {
    val child : Child = Child()
}

class Child {
    fun doSomethingWithParent(parent : Parent) = Foo()
}

class Foo
```

And a list of `Parents`:

```
val list = List<Parent>(10){_ -> Parent()}
```

Instead of mapping with

```
list.map { it.child.doSomethingWithParent(it) } // works
```

to use a function reference to `doSomethingWithParent` like

```
// does not work
list.map(Child::doSomethingWithParent)
list.map(Parent::child::doSomethingWithParent)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this

`map` requires `transform: (T) -> R` (≈ `KFunction1<T,R>`) function

`Child::doSomethingWithParent` is `KFunction2<Child, Parent, Foo>` (≈ `f: (Child, Parent) -> Foo`). It's method reference therefore it requires an object on which the function will be invoked (`Child` parameter)

You can do something like this:

```
class Parent {
    val child: Child = Child()

    fun foo() = child.doSomethingWithParent(this)
}

val l1 = list.map(Parent::foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

The clue is in the error messages.  (Which is why it's usually a good idea to give them in the question…)

In your line:

```
list.map(Child::doSomethingWithParent)
```

*which* child should do something with each the listed parent?  You're not specifying that it's the listed parent's child.

And in your line:

```
list.map(Parent::child::doSomethingWithParent)
```

what is the second `::` supposed to indicate?  `Parent::child` is a method reference, not a class or object.